# Why too many threads in weblogic with TIMED_WAITING status for "java.util.TimerThread.run"

Tags: java, out-of-memory, weblogic

I'm facing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Theses errors occurs with some frequency always in two stacks:

First

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.doExecute(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:213)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.execute(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:171)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.submit(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.doSubmit(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:189)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.invoke(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
```

Second

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
        at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:160)
        at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:132)
        at org.cfg4j.source.reload.strategy.PeriodicalReloadStrategy.<init>(PeriodicalReloadStrategy.java:58)
```

The number of threads is about 9287 threads:

```
jstack <pid> | grep "java.lang.Thread.State" | wc -l
9287
```

98% of the threads are in the TIMED_WAITING below

```
jstack <pid> | grep "at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop" | wc -l
9114
```

```
"Timer-5962" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4c10769000 nid=0x1a6a1 in Object.wait() [0x00007f4bc62ae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
        - locked <0x00000006d0297f28> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

As I have 10.000 threads * 256k  + heap of 4 GB, so I have at least about 6.5 GB of memory consumed. With 4 nodes I'm reaching the size limit of RAM memory of my server. So I think it is the cause of OutOfMemory.

Note: the server has no thread limitation

Why do I have so many threads with TIMED_WAITING in java.util.TimerThread.run stack? Are my applications causing it or is it weblogic server fault? How can I figure out the source of this stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I figure out that was the problem. We're using a library called cfg4j-core and whenever a run the code below it creates a new thead using java.util.Timer.

It was supposed to cache the properties by 30 seconds, but it seems that is not working.

In result the number of threads created always increase and it finishes with OutOfMemory.

```
        ConfigFilesProvider configFilesProvider = new FilesPropertiesProvider(locations);
        ConfigurationProvider configurationProvider = new ConfigurationProviderBuilder()
            .withConfigurationSource(new FilesConfigurationSource(configFilesProvider))
            .withReloadStrategy(new PeriodicalReloadStrategy(cacheSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .build();
        return configurationProvider.bind("config", SystemProperties.class);
```

Comment: The problem is not in cfg4j, we we're supposed to call only once configurationprovider, it means, create a singleton of that, but whenever we need a configuration we cal the entire code again.

Comment: I realize this is quite old, but how were you able to identify this? Was it just backtracking of recent changes, or did anything in the traces point to it?